# 'Cron' package not working as expected in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm facing some problem in nodeJS Cron package. It doesn't work properly. sometimes the job didn't start. My cron job code -

```
const updateDocJob = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 30 05 * * *', 
  onTick: function() {
    // send the notification mail to me for notifying about the job running
    sendNotificationMail('Doc Update JOB', 'START');
    // perform some functionality & db operation
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
});

updateDocJob.start();
```

As you can see in the code, I've added the notification mail system, So that I can verify the job (whether it starts or not). Main issue -

- Job didn't start on from May 31 to June 4. (I didn't get the notify mail in between these dates) Despite, The mail logic works perfectly.

I'm not able to track the issue behind this. I've checked the server logs between these dates but didn't find any errors in that. (I'm using the meteor galaxy server for application deployment)

Is there any problem with node package?

Comment: Just FYI, this snippet is not valid. Before `start: false` you've got an extra closing parenthesis, should be `},`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: You can also use `updateDocJob.running` to verify if the job started correctly

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni thanks for your view on this. Actually, my code working correctly because I got the notification mail for other dates. But yes, while writing the post I forgot to remove one extra bracket '}'.

Comment: so the code works, but you didn't receive mails just on those days?